# New button not displayed

Tags: jquery

Html code

When I press "Submit Rows" I need another button to appear with Name "Submit" Which 
I am not getting.  Can anyone tell me what is problem here ?

```
<div id="itemRows">Enter number of rows :
<input type="text" name="nrows" size="4" />
<input onclick="firststage(this.form);" type="button" value="Submit Rows" />
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
function firststage() {
var button = '<input onclick="secondStage();" type="button" value="Submit Columns">';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(button);
}


function secondStage(frm) {}
```

Comment: Check the browser console for any possible error ?

Comment: Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bZJ7Z/3/

Comment: Fiddle              http://jsfiddle.net/bZJ7Z/3/

Comment: Your function definitions are wrapped in an `onLoad` function; you should use "no wrap" in jsFiddle ... when you do this, you will see that jQuery isn't defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included `jquery` files into your fiddle. Check this working [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bZJ7Z/5/). Note that I haven't made any changes in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I am first time user :)

Comment: @user3218094 you are welcome(and +1 to your question for providing fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `jQuery` why not use it completely

check your code works [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/LgH4V/)

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you're forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle.

However, instead of nested `onclick` and function, you can do:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var button = '<input onclick="secondStage();" type="button" value="Submit Columns"/>';
    $('#itemRows').append(button);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZJ7Z/7/)**